# Clearing conditionally hidden inputs

Tags: webforms

Am I misunderstanding how this works?

https://www.drupal.org/node/3003163#comment-13134024

We have checked "Clear Value(s) When Hidden" but the values in the hidden fields are not cleared and are submitted with visible form fields.

1. Enter value in fields Sitting and Year.
2. Hide "Sitting" and "Year" fields by selecting another conditional field, General Assembly.
3. "Sitting" and "Year" fields are not cleared when hidden.
4. Values are submitted for "Sitting" and "Year".

&general_assembly=65&sitting=spring&year=2016

Comment: This sounds like a bug triggered by populating conditionally hidden inputs.  Please create a ticket in the Webform module's issue queue.  Please include an example webform.

Comment: My mistake. We are hijacking the submit button to grab values directly from the DOM rather than getting them from webform state.Confirmed that the values are being cleared from state.